# Gitlab hosting issue in linode VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, gitlab, linode

I purchased a linode 1 GB plan recently. I have installed the basic LAMP stack on it.
I wanted to install gitlab on the server. I followed the documentation at: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md

The documentation also says the official server is Nginx and I have got Nginx start with no issues.
Problem is when I start the gitlab service using:

```
sudo service gitlab start
```

I get:

```
rm: cannot remove `/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket': No such file or directory
bash: bundle: command not found
GitLab service started
```

Comment: The last log message states that the service is running , isn't it?

Comment: It says so. But when I issue the command: `sudo service gitlab status`, it says "GitLab service is not running."

Comment: it said `bundle: command not found` do you have ruby installed ?

Comment: The output ruby -v is as follows:
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: I solved the issue by restarting my linode instance